# add a marker (like star) to questions indicating "I'm working on it"

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes I may start thinking about an answer but I am unable to finish it due to various reasons. Most often it is that I have to change my location (work to home, vice versa) or I have to look something up or kill the tab. Once that happens I sometimes lose the question.

I would like some way of marking a question as "in progress" or "in my queue" or some such so I can easily resume pondering the question after interruptions.

- This is solely for the answerer's
  (me) benefit.
- It is not a "save drafts" proposal.
- It might be nice to
  see how many others are working on
  the same question. Then again, maybe
  not. Might be nice to see the level
  of interest *after* a question was
  answered.

Comment: Marking it a favorite doesn't work for you?

Comment: See [List all my drafts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73148/list-all-my-drafts), which is semi-related.

Comment: @John Saunders: I do not want to mix my favorites with anything else. I hate to have to weed.

Comment: @marcog: Yes, something like that but lighter. Just a "I'm thinking about these questions". Could also be a useful moderation tool: mark several questions for a tentative move, for example.