# Better drafts feature for questions

Tags: feature-request, editor, draft

The [current draft functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting) is at best quite lame.

I think it would be easier to ask better questions [*if I could draft my questions and have any number of drafts I like*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73148/list-all-my-drafts), like in a standard email client.

One draft isn't enough.

Comment: I'd be happy with two.

Comment: "at best quite lame" those are fighting words, we decided on a trivial/transparent implementation that does not make you think. It just works, no need to manage and keep track of drafts.

Comment: @waffles Just my honest-to-goodness opinion, healthy as homemade waffles with plenty of butter and syrup. Mmm mmm good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd think asking people to "manage drafts" was some laborious and irksome chore…  I'd argue the opposite.  For *me*, having only one draft **SERIOUSLY** wigs me out.

The brain is a complex machine. People - and the world around us - are by nature, ever changing and complicated… Unfortunately, as is proven by the faceless down-voting of this thread.. "some people" often forget that everyone except *themself*... is "having a different life experience".

On drafts:  we know the capability exists.. (we are able to have ONE draft).  However, the current implementation's essential lock-in to a single-train-of-thought - is heavy-handed and unnecessary.

The more flexible a tool becomes, the more adept and comfortable  people become at using it.  A fear of feature-creep is the enemy of innovation - and only warranted in an environment lacking in sound judgement and effective checks and balances.

Don't assume what people want.  Meta is overrun with control-freaks, IMO.. whom for one reason or another are very averse to change.  I swear, everyone needs to take a deep breath sometimes, step back, and realize what we're trying to do here..  Provide an *accessible* and *adaptable* system for **PEOPLE**.  Provide as many ways to interact as possible, and strive towards breaking down barriers to entry.

As the site matures, it is becoming more and more about new ways to allow new, (or possibly former/disenchanted) users to explore and contribute in their own, unique ways.. even if it's not YOUR way… This kind of flexibility will lead to more rich contributions, and a better community.

Answer (score 9):

Multiple drafts seems like it would be a feature useful only to a small number of heavy users, but confusing or overkill to typical users.

My opinion only, of course.  I could be wrong.  (And regardless, if you want a feature, you certainly should be asking for it. But I can see why this may not be a priority for Stack Exchange developers.)

Comment: -1 because you are wrong

Comment: +1 because you are right

Comment: If _multiple drafts_ are "confusing" to "these people".. are they really people that should be "using this site"?

Comment: Even more: I've always figured a draft was actually a backup, just in case one's internet connection fails, or something like that.

Comment: Yes, he is wrong.

Comment: "...confusing [] to typical users" Really? Reeeeally? Put any random half-ass UX-designer on it and the ones who don't want to use it won't even have to know it's there in the first place.