# Expand draft feature to allow multiple drafts

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, draft

The draft feature was discussed a lot [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting) and in other posts, but I didn't see much talk about the OP's mention of being able to have multiple.

> Optionally, allow multiple draft questions and a page to edit/delete them.

I think the draft feature where it autosaves and stores it server-side is great, but in most things where they have a draft feature (like email clients), they allow you to have multiple drafts (also stored server-side).  The expiration can even work the same as it does for the single draft system right now.

You wouldn't even need full page to store them, I think the user profile page could have a tab for it like it currently has for answers, questions, and everything else.

[image: question]

It could look very similar to how questions look, with it's title and tags listed there.

Comment: I asked this [10,000,000 years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73148/list-all-my-drafts) and brought it up again [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113416/better-drafts-feature-for-questions).  Way to kick the sleeping unicorn.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The other one asks for a list of existing drafts, this one here asks to have more than a single draft per site. Reopened.

Comment: [As I mentioned in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6088697#6088697), while this isn't a *critical* feature, it would be a nice 'quality of life' improvement.

Answer (score 11):

**While this isn't a critical feature, it would be a nice 'quality of life' improvement.**

Funnily enough the Stack Exchange mobile app ***does*** allow users to store multiple drafts at once. You can even view all your drafts from each SE site simultaneously.

[image: Viewing multiple drafts on iOS]

It would be nice to see this feature make the transition from mobile to desktop. It's annoying when you accidentally overwriting a lengthy, detailed post, because you forgot to save the question [to an external site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297226/351462).

Comment: that could be an app local feature. The website stores drafts server side.