# Draft a question

Tags: feature-request, posting, draft

Would it be possible to draft a post/questions, as this could be good in creating, editing and formatting questions prior to posting them.

I have searched the meta and found [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting) in reference to this feature, but that post has a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag, but I can't see anywhere such feature.

Probably I am missing it somewhere. I don't see it on the ask question page. Where can I draft it and save for future posting?

#### EDIT:

From the answer: Single draft saving is present.

I am requesting for multiple draft saving feature. Can we forward this as a new feature-request?

Comment: Your edit makes your question a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/draft-feature-expanded-to-multiple-drafts, which was closed as a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73148/list-all-my-drafts (but I'm not certain it actually is).

Comment: @Ben __It definitely is__. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73148/list-all-my-drafts

Comment: I [added a suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145221/111307) to the original feature request

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Drafts are auto-saved. Try this:

1. Click Ask Question
2. Write something into the question field
3. Click outside the field to blur, and wait a few seconds (not sure this is needed)
4. Close the window
5. Open the site in a new window, and click ask question again. Your draft should be there.

Comment: I downvoted because the user was asking for multiple draft saved.

Comment: Yes, but he only made that clear *after* I answered. But okay, I can live with that downvote :P

Comment: @bfaretto: sorry.. i can't edit the downvote anymore. I apologize.

Comment: Don't worry, @Revious. I should have edited the answer after the clarification from the OP anyway. I guess I deserved a downvote for that ;)

Answer (score 7):

From the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/158100) to the question:

> If you start asking a question, but do not successfully submit, you will see your last saved question draft the next time you visit the ask a question page.

The feature is not for multiple drafts, but a draft for the *current* (and only) question.