# A process for multiple drafts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, draft

Comment about the [linked possible duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145100/13295): "*yes I had read it, but there are not convincing answers, in particular for multi draft questions. It's not complicated, it suffices to add a drafts space for each users, that's all*".

---

If we want to have many drafts (questions or answers), we can post it and delete it immediately.
When we have an improvement to do, we undelete the post, we do the edit, and we re-delete it.
When the post is completed, we can choose to undelete it, for good.

Is this process allowed ?
Else, how do otherwise ?

Comment: You don't even have to undelete it to edit.

Comment: *how do otherwise*: Not hit 'submit' until you are done editing? The site *already* saves a draft periodically for you.

Comment: If you post immediately some garbage just to be on top I would say: No

Comment: And why would you have "many drafts"? Why not focus on a single post at a time?

Comment: @MartijnPieters : are you sure, I test it on math.SE but I obtain the page: "a deleted post can't be edited".

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: Certainly answers can be edited, even when deleted. Perhaps questions cannot.

Comment: @Bart : Some prefer to work on multiple posts at the same time, others on one.

Comment: Once again, the fact that the possible duplicate has no convincing answers does not imply it is not a duplicate. If you wish to attract more answers/opinions, offer a bounty explicitly stating so.

Comment: @Bart : the post [Draft a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145100/draft-a-question) asks about **one** draft, and has an answer *accepted* by the OP. Here I ask about **multiple** drafts, this needs a completely different answer, in my opinion.

Answer (score 9):

When you start a post (a question or an answer), the site *already* saves a draft of your work from time to time:

> [image: draft saved]

Note that you can edit deleted answers too, you do not need to undelete. However, there is *no* need to go to to such lengths just to get a draft feature, it is already there.

If you tried to get in an answer with the oldest timestamp this way, then just don't. Good answers get voted up, if put in the time to write a better answer, there is no need to be *first* all the time.

Multiple question drafts are not supported; I'd personally not use your trick to edit multiple questions, ever. Use a file in a local text editor if you need to save multiple drafts for questions instead. Deleting and undeleting questions is likely to attract moderator attention flags for suspicious behaviour instead. Self-deletes also factor heavily into the question-ban algorithm.

Perhaps instead, you should focus on each question in turn and make sure it meets quality standards and your undivided attention, to get the best answers.

Comment: It's ok for answers, but what about questions, if we want to work on many questions in the same time.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: Work on *one* question at a time. Why do you need to work on multiple questions?

Comment: Why not ? Each has its working methods.

Comment: Anyway, you do not answer the question : is it allowed?

Comment: Sure, but depending on your post scores and how many deleted posts you have, you might possibly find yourself postbanned at some point.

Comment: **Local text editor** : not very comfortable (layout...), especially in mathematics (latex).
**Quality** : that's why starting with a draft is preferable. **Suspicious** : that's why I ask about another way, and that why I put [tag: feature-request].

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: I only meant for the local text editor to be a place to save a draft, not to edit it.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux to your "why not?": because interruption is bad. If you interrupt your work on a question to do something else, your question will likely suffer from that.

Comment: So ok, it would be allowed but frowned upon. So this would an idea of improvement for SE, not very difficult and that might be useful.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: your feature request is a dupe of [Draft a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145100)

Comment: @Stijn : I am not convinced by this argument, however, sometimes there is a saturation phenomenon, and do something else can "take a breath".

Comment: @MartijnPieters : yes I had read it, but there are not convincing answers, in particular for multi draft questions. It's not complicated, it suffices to add a drafts space for each users, that's all.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux You can always offer a bounty on that duplicate to draw in new answers.

Comment: @Bart : I have just 129 reputation points... You could do it without problem with your 36120 reputation points :-)

Comment: It's your request, not mine @SébastienPalcoux. 50 rep is not a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Self-deletion and self-undeletion of answers exists to solve a very specific, very simple problem. A user posts an answer that is wrong. They are informed that it is wrong. That person could just edit their answer to fix it, but during the time they did so, others could be being actively misled by it. So it's best to redact it, fix it in your own time, then restore it.

That's what the feature is intended to do for answers.

Self-deletion of *questions* however is a rather different thing. I'm personally of the opinion that self-deletion of questions is a dubious practice in general. However, some people do sometimes post questions that they shouldn't have. Perhaps they contain copywritten information. Or whatever.

Self-undeletion of questions exists mainly to serve the same needs as self-undeletion for answers: fixing acute problems with a question without causing people to be confused.

In both cases, these legitimate uses for this feature are for problems that could and *should* have been worked out *before* posting the question/answer. We allow it because everyone makes mistakes.

It should *never* be part of your basic workflow or otherwise your standard procedure for posting on the site. It's for *exceptional* circumstances.