# Can I find the draft of my question that was deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, draft

I put a lot of effort into drafting a question, and received some comments and updates via email, but when I log in I'm just greeted with a page saying the question was deleted, and none of the "similar questions" are similar at all.

Is it possible to find the text that I spent quite some time drafting? I do not have copies in my email, only abbreviated snippets are included, not enough to reconstruct the whole question.

Comment: You are able to view your own deleted questions. Maybe you asked that question from another account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you received comments and updates, it's not just a [draft](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145101/295232), but it actually has been published. You can view your recently deleted questions by going to the Questions tab on your profile on the appropriate site (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/users/764312/dagelf?tab=questions) and click the 'Deleted recent questions' link.