# How can I share an unfinished answer without using the Sandbox?

Tags: discussion, answers, sandbox

Occasionally, when I find myself working on a [particularly lengthy answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/73807/48480), I'll want to share my answer with a friend or college to ask questions or receive feedback before posting. My typical workaround is to post answers I want to share in the [formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/351462) if they aren't ready for submssion.

I don't enjoy this solution, as it feels like an unintended use of the sandbox. It bumps the formatting sandbox to Meta's front page, is only possible for [users with 10+ rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question), and crowds more answers onto a post that, [according to Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment960661_3122), was already overflowing with 900+ answers before it was [wiped clean and archived](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296077/sandbox-archive).

**Is there a better way to share unfinished questions or answers before posting?**

Comment: An off-site resource like pastebin or GH gist?

Comment: @zondo To my surprise, [it seems Gist renders SE's markdown with no issue!](https://gist.github.com/Stevoisiak/9800217b9dce0a0d00eaf8ec70ec09b4) The only requirement is that you add `.md` when setting your gist's filename.

Comment: Ah, yes. I forgot about formatting. Pastebin really isn't a good option for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Github gists](https://gist.github.com) support markdown (not SE's specific flavour, but close enough to be helpful). Note that you will need to indicate it is a markdown file by using the .md extension.

Very similar to Github gists, you could use a [Gitlab snippet](https://gitlab.com/explore/snippets).

Not to be left out, Bitbucket also has [snippets](https://bitbucket.org/dashboard/snippets), but I can't verify that they support markdown since I've never used them.