# Adding draft questions in one's account

Tags: feature-request, draft

I need a feature for saving draft posts in my account in some sites like Math.SE. I use different computers and sometimes have several questions to be asked once I find a computer with internet access. At least I don't forget them if I can save them in my account instead of discarding them before 20min obstacle or similar rules.

Comment: I don't understand: how can you access to a S.E website and write a draft first if you don't have Internet connection?

Comment: @MaximeLorant I think he means "I can only ask a question once every 20 minutes (due to rate limiting), so I'd like to draft all my questions so I don't forget them before I can ask them all

Comment: @psubsee2003 Oh ok, make sense. Never reach this *20min rate limit*, I don't even know it was existing.

Comment: @MaximeLorant Just for your reference, the [Complete Rate Limiting Guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) details everything, but new users with <125 rep can only ask 1 question every 20 minutes.

Comment: Oops, better: [Better drafts feature for questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113416/better-drafts-feature-for-questions)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of these sites is for when you've exhausted all research and attempts and still not been able to solve your problem so then post a question. Therefore you shouldn't ever really *have* a batch of questions to ask.

If you do then you probably haven't done enough investigation to solve them individually already.

Being able to batch then up ready to post would just encourage people not to do enough investigation, people will just write their questions in advance and post them all up.

Comment: I disagree.  I can achieve what the OP is asking locally in a text file, but actually writing the question helps with research as you often find different things to search for when you try to explain your problem to other people

Comment: Isn't the other point of these sites to gather all the information in one, easily accessible place?