# Drafts folder on website

Tags: feature-request, draft

As stated in [List all my drafts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73148), the SE network only allows one draft per site.

However, in the iOS app, there's a folder for 'Drafts,' in which you can save multiple drafts (for questions) for each site:

[image]

With multiple drafts:

[image]

Why don't we have this functionality on the regular website? Can we please copy this feature to the website?

Or, at the very least, can we make it so we can write multiple drafts for a SE site?

Comment: You can't just "copy this feature", those are totally different things, on various levels.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not literally copy like copy-paste, but create identical/similar functionality on the website

Comment: Well, that is most likely more complicated to do than it sounds.

Comment: @ShadowWizard As for the duplicate, was I supposed to have been able to find that closed question? I didn't see it come up when I was searching for an answer to this question

Comment: No, that's fine. It wasn't trivial to find, plus it was (wrongly) closed. All good now, you can keep this one here as well, no need to delete.